# I'm going to use the 'raycaster' to select one of the 'objects' to zoom in

Tags: math, three.js

I'm going to use the 'raycaster' to select one of the 'objects' to zoom in, 
but When the camera moves to an object, it bends instead of going straight.
Now how do you go diagonally as it bends to the coordinate point?

Here is my code:

```
if(mouseup && (selectobject!==undefined ||selectobject!==null)) {
  //Calculate distance to camera and selectobjectca
  var distance =
    Math.sqrt(
      (
        (selectobject.point.x-camera.position.x) * (selectobject.point.x-camera.position.x)
      ) +
      (
        (selectobject.point.y-camera.position.y) * (selectobject.point.y-camera.position.y)
      ) +
      (
        (selectobject.point.z-camera.position.z) * (selectobject.point.z-camera.position.z)
      )
    )

    if(distance>100) {
      camera.lookAt(selectobject.point)
      console.log('camera.position ',camera.position.x)
      if(  camera.position.x < selectobject.point.x &&
           Math.abs(selectobject.point.x-camera.position.x) > 50) {
        camera.position.x += xratio
      } else if(camera.position.x < selectobject.point.x &&
                Math.abs(selectobject.point.x-camera.position.x) > 50) {
        camera.position.x -= xratio
      }
      if(  camera.position.y < selectobject.point.y &&
           Math.abs(selectobject.point.y-camera.position.y) > 50) {
        camera.position.y+=yratio
      } else if (camera.position.y > selectobject.point.y &&
                 Math.abs(selectobject.point.y-camera.position.y) > 50) {
        camera.position.y-=yratio
      }
      if(  camera.position.z<selectobject.point.z &&
           Math.abs(selectobject.point.z-camera.position.z) > 50) {
        camera.position.z+=zratio
      } else if(camera.position.z>selectobject.point.z &&
                Math.abs(selectobject.point.z-camera.position.z) > 50) {
        camera.position.z-=zratio
      }
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    } else {
      controls.update()
      mouseup = false
    }
  } else {
    mouseup = false
}
```

[image: handdrawing]

Comment: xratio = Math.abs(Math.abs(camera.position.x)-Math.abs(selectobject.point.x))/100
yratio = Math.abs(Math.abs(camera.position.y)-Math.abs(selectobject.point.y))/100
zratio = Math.abs(Math.abs(camera.position.z)-Math.abs(selectobject.point.z))/80

Comment: FYI, there are functions to get [the distance between 2 points](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Vector3.distanceTo) as well as functions to [move to a point](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Vector3.lerp) and [move between 2 points](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Vector3.lerpVectors)